# jQuery: Set data attribute to an element before appending it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On clicking a button, I want to copy `html` of an `input` and append it to the parent `div`, but before appending I want to change the `data-id` attribute of it.

Following code copies and appends the field correctly, how can I set the value of the data-id attribute to the timestamp?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event){
    
  var timestamp = Date.now(); //set this as data attribute

  var input = $(this).parent().find('input').prop('outerHTML');
  $(this).parent().append(input); //set data-id to timestamp before appending  
 
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.field {
  width: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" class="input" data-id="1" /><button>+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event) {

  var timestamp = Date.now(); //set this as data attribute
  
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  
  parent.find('input:first')
    .clone()
    .attr('data-id', timestamp)
    .appendTo(parent)

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.field {
  width: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" class="input" data-id="1" /><button>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Small tweak needed to preventing cloning all... use `:first` selector or `first()` or eq(0) or something to only return one

Answer (score 1):

Use [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy the whole element as a new jQuery object.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event){
    
  var timestamp = Date.now(); //set this as data attribute

  var $input = $(this).siblings('input:first').clone();
  $input.data('id',timestamp) 
  $(this).parent().append($input); //set data-id to timestamp before appending  
  
  // show the data values for demo only
  $('input').val(function(){
      return $(this).data('id')
  })
 
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.field {
  width: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" class="input" data-id="1" /><button>+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.attr( attributeName, value )` check the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event){
    
  var timestamp = Date.now(); //set this as data attribute

  var input = $(this).parent().find('input').prop('outerHTML');
  
  $(this).parent().append($(input).attr("data-id", timestamp)); //set data-id to timestamp before appending  
 
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.field {
  width: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" class="input" data-id="1" /><button>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't doing what you think it is. outerHtml returns a string, not a jQ object

Comment: I appended the old value of the input, my fault. anyway, I updated the code, try it now